# Given all libraries extracted from a Fat Jar, how to rebuild the source code?

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, fatjar, maven-repository

There is a Fat Jar, built with Spring Boot and Maven. Its internal structure can be explored, using [Java Decompiler](http://java-decompiler.github.io/). Notice the "**lib**" node, which is supposed to contain all libraries needed to run the Fat Jar.

[image]

The Fat Jar can execute successfully under JDK/JRE 1.8 as a standalone application. Using 7z, one can extract the Fat Jar and collect all libraries embedded in it.

I have the source code (Maven with POM.XML) that was used to build the Fat Jar, and I would like to modify it (**no** new additional library added). Put it simply, *comment a few line of code*, then recompile it (it will be again a Fat Jar).

**Question**: The problem is: when recompiling the source code (command: `mvn package`), *one of repository is no longer accessible from Internet*. Is there a definite way (step by step) to recompile? In theory, this should be possible as we already have all needed libraries to run the Jar (thanks to "Fat Jar" feature).

##### My Attempt:

1. Extract the Fat Jar.
2. Using `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>` to install one by one library into local Maven repository (`c:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository\`). Then later, I can execute `mvn package` against the main source code, with the assumption that all libraries needed are available in the local Maven repo; thus, no need to fetch it from Internet.
3. But I got a lot of problems, e.g. 'groupId' is missing.

Comment: _Why_ is the libraries no longer available online?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `install:install-file` the missing libraries to your local repository and set the GAV (groupId, artifactId, version) correctly when installing it.

Generally, I would also check if there is an easier way to solve your problem than patching the library.